# Firebird group by retrieve extra data

Tags: sql, group-by, firebird

I have a table with 6 columns: `id`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`. `id` is primary key.

I am trying to retrieve distinct a, b, c, max(d) for that group, and e that is present in the same row as max(d) is (column "id" is not relevant for my query).

I tried this query:

```
SELECT a, b, c, MAX(d), e
FROM tablename
GROUP BY a, b, c;
```

but it gives me "Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause).". If I add an extra GROUP BY e, it just gives me distinct a, b, c, e, with a MAX(d) for each, which is not what I need. I do understand why this happens, what I don't understand is how to make it do what I need...

Is a subquery the way to go? Could you write one for me?

The most frustrating thing is that my query would work in MySQL :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.a,t1.b,t1.c,t1.d,t1.e
FROM tablename AS t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT a, b, c, MAX(d) d
            FROM tablename
            GROUP BY a, b, c
           ) AS t2
ON  t1.a = t2.a
AND t1.b = t2.b
AND t1.c = t2.c
AND t1.d = t2.d
```

Note that if multiple rows are tied for `MAX(d)`, this query will return all of the rows of `a,b,c` with that `d` value.

I don't know how MySQL deals with duplicate rows in this scenario.